# How to build an observation space for a game in an RL gym environment?

Tags: python, reinforcement-learning, openai-gym

I am currently trying to grasp my head around Reinforcement Learning using PythonGym for a project. Specifically, I've got a custom Mario-like game which the agent should learn to play.
I already created a way for the python code to access the game state by preparing it in the game code and sending it as JSON through a socket, however, I am not quite sure about how to build the observation space using this game state, especially because the size of the state isn't fixed.
The following is an example of the game state:

```
{
        "entities":[{"dx":0,"dy":0,"x":224,"y":82},{"dx":0,"dy":0,"x":656,"y":82},{"dx":0,"dy":0,"x":736,"y":82},{"dx":0,"dy":0,"x":864,"y":82}],
        "objects":[{"texture":"jump-blocks","x":112,"y":48},{"texture":"keys-and-locks","x":368,"y":80},{"texture":"jump-blocks","x":1040,"y":48},
                   {"texture":"jump-blocks","x":1168,"y":48},{"texture":"keys-and-locks","x":1264,"y":80},{"texture":"jump-blocks","x":1456,"y":48},
                   {"texture":"jump-blocks","x":1568,"y":48}],
        "player":{"dx":0,"dy":0,"score":0,"x":0,"y":76},
        "tileMatrix":[[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
                      [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
                      [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
                      [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
                      [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0],
                      [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0],
                      [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1],
                      [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1],
                      [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1],
                      [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1]]
}
```

"entities" are the enemies which can be killed (and are then deleted from the game state), "objects" are mostly the jump blocks, where sometimes gems can pop out and also be added to the game state, and also some kind of key and lock system, which is a requirement to finish the level.
"player" should be self-explanatory and "tileMatrix" is a simple representation of the direct environment where the player currently is. Every 1 represents a collidable tile, although the jump blocks are not included here.

I know that I need to use the Box spaces to prepare a fitting Tensor that can hold all these values, but I am not sure how to do that.
I also know that there might be the alternative to just capture a screenshot of the game in every step and use that as the observation space, but I figured that the agent would learn better with the actual game state.

Any hint on a solution is greatly appreciated.